# WPF - Programmatic Binding on a BitmapEffect

Tags: wpf, data-binding, bitmapeffect

I would like to be able to **programmatically** bind some data to the dependency properties on a **BitmapEffect**. With a FrameworkElement like TextBlock there is a SetBinding method where you can programmatically do these bindings like:

```
myTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("SomeProperty"));
```

And I know you can do it in straight XAML (as seen below)

```
<TextBlock Width="Auto" Text="Some Content" x:Name="MyTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" >
    <TextBlock.BitmapEffect>
        <BitmapEffectGroup>
            <OuterGlowBitmapEffect x:Name="MyGlow" GlowColor="White" GlowSize="{Binding Path=MyValue}" />
        </BitmapEffectGroup>
    </TextBlock.BitmapEffect>
</TextBlock>
```

But I can't figure out how to accomplish this with C# because BitmapEffect doesn't have a SetBinding method.

I've tried:

```
myTextBlock.SetBinding(OuterGlowBitmapEffect.GlowSize, new Binding("SomeProperty") { Source = someObject });
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [BindingOperation.SetBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx):

```
Binding newBinding = new Binding();
newBinding.ElementName = "SomeObject";
newBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(SomeObjectType.SomeProperty);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(MyGlow, OuterGlowBitmapEffect.GlowSizeProperty, newBinding);
```

I think that should do what you want.